# Flutter: How to know the size of a flutter plugin

Tags: flutter, plugins

Adding many plugins can increase `Flutter Apps` size too much. But sometimes I find two similar plugins and if I have to choose them based on **lesser size**, how would I do it?
I couldn't find any tools for checking its size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flutter has a tool for measuring your app size it's documented [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/perf/app-size).
But the TLDR is:

1. Run `flutter build apk --analyze-size --target-platform=android-arm`
2. Run `flutter pub global run devtools --appSizeBase=apk-code-size-analysis_04.json` or whichever name the output of the previous command json was.

That should give you a look like this.

[image: dev tools]

And then you can explore how much space each package, asset or whatever thats inside your app occupies.